# Get the id value from the page url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

In SharePoint how do you get the ID value from the url of the page you are on using javascript( Jquery,ajax, Rest..),  e.g. I have the url like so: `http:// ddd/mypage?ID=xx`   I tried before to retrieve the full url but it didn't get the ID and its value. so I have to get the ID value directly with the get method

Comment: Ok, so in order to make this work where do I enter the code listed above? - At the end of the page URL? - In a Script Editor web part? - Other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem resolved. Thanks for your contribution.

There is the code to get the ID value:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("=");
var ID= vars[1];
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it assumes the ID is the first and ONLY parameter specified in the query string.  Please use Aanchal's or Naddeem's solution instead.

Comment: but this solution work for me, because the only paramter is the ID, so for Aanchal's or Naddeem's solution instead, it dosen't work for me, and i find this solution easy to use

Answer (score 15):

you can use SharePoint’s `GetUrlKeyValue()` function to get item id. Example:

```
var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, location.href);
```

Comment: Interesting, so many built in functions. One could also use: JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); JSRequest.QueryString["ID"]

Answer (score 6):

Use the following javascript function :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {  
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"), results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var prodId = getParameterByName('prodId');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                if (!url) url = window.location.href;
                name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
                if (!results) return null;
                if (!results[2]) return '';
                return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
```

//ID Get//

```
var mid = getParameterByName("ID", window.location.href);
```