# How to get SharePoint ID given only item URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, item

Looking for the simplest possible solution, but needs to be JavaScript/jQuery if at all possible.

I have an XML document that I am transforming using XSLT to render an HTML page. This XML document contains a link to another XML document. The only information in the source XML about the linked document is an absolute URL.

Using only the URL of the document, how can I retrieve the document's ID?

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100354/get-the-id-value-from-the-page-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the absolute URL isn't the best, but it's something :)

You'll better need to have the site relative URL for the file, which you can pass then to *GetFileByServerRelativeUrl* available in *Web* object, using the correct *Web* where the file is.
This method is available also in CSOM and REST API, so you can build and issue the REST query directly from your JS.

See [Working with files by using REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#Files)

If your documents are coming from different libraries, sites or site collection it can be challenging to 'compose' the relative URL properly, but if they're all residing in the same *Web* shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Thanks! I can actually predict with 100% certainty that the documents will be coming from the same library. Does that simplify things?

Comment: yes, if you use the CSOM approach (clientContext) then you probably can just use SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_web(), without having to open different webs for different documents. In case you go for the REST approach you can just assume the starting URL to be: http://<yoursite>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('<doc relative url>') just replacing last parameter for different files