# How to get ID from url with javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have the following url:

```
http://myweb/sites/stonehr/SitePages/VacancyTracking.aspx?PrID=23?Status=34
```

And I have to get the value of `PrID=` and `Status=` with JavaScript, to be able to:

```
alert(PrID); // output should be 23
alert(Status); // output should be 34
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Pretty common question. Read here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100354/get-the-id-value-from-the-page-url

Comment: And all that SharePoint provides concerning URL parameters: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do/159290#159290